# For django-model-utils, how can `select_subclasses()` be applied to fields of an object?

Tags: django, django-model-utils

I have some models like this:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    pass

class Parent(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='items')
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass

class RedHeadedStepChild(Parent):
    pass
```

Is it possible to use `select_subclasses()` to prefetch fields in the container?  I want to do something like this:

```
qs = Container.objects.all().prefetch_related('items')\
     .select_subclasses() # <---
```

So that the `items` related field of each `Container` is retrieved in each of its respective subclass types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```python
Container.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('items', Parent.objects.select_subclasses())
)
```

Comment: This is the bee's knees.  I've been working around this issue for months and now I have the solution.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the typo edit. I copy pasted `select_suclasses()` from your original question so you might want to correct it there too. Cheers.