# How can polymorphic items be broken into their respective related lists on a container?

Tags: django

Say I have a set of models like this:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    pass

class Parent(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='%(class)s_list')

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Without making `Parent` abstract, is it possible to make `Child`'s `container` field have a related name of `child_list` instead and all `Child`'s instances would be put in `child_list` for the `Container` model?

I've tried modifying `Child` to have an additional field:

```
class Child(Parent):
    container2 = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='%(class)s_list')
```

And then making the two fields be in sync'.  However, since the real goal of this is to optimize a parent class with *many* inheritance-related children [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014085/for-django-model-utils-how-can-select-subclasses-be-applied-to-fields-of-an), using an aliased `Container` key doesn't populate the cache correctly when doing a prefetch.

Any solution would probably cause an aliasing issue with `Child` instance in list `child_list` into `sample_list`.  However, I'm not intending to expose `sample_list` and I'd be happy to work around aliasing.

Comment: Please confirm that you intend for `Parent` model to have public properties that the `Child` model should not have.  If this is the case, are you aware that querying `Parent.objects` will include `Child` rows instantiated as `Parent`?

Comment: Yeah, `Parent.objects` would have the `Child` instances as `Parent` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a wicked answer:

- Create a `Container` pointer in the `Parent` and the `Child` and keep them in sync'.
- Use `select_subclasses()` from [`django-model-utils`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) to populate the `parent_list` with all the different `Child` objects.
- wrapper [`QuerySet`'s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api) `_prefetch_related_objects` so that after the original call, the child objects are split into their respective buckets into `_prefetched_objects_cache`
- wrapper `QuerySet`'s `_clone` function in order to re-wraper  `_prefetch_related_objects()` each time the `QuerySet` is `_clone()`'d

```
# get all the subclasses of the `Parent` type
# from http://stackoverflow.com/a/408465/20712
def find_subclasses(module, clazz):
    return [
        cls
            for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(module)
                if inspect.isclass(cls) and issubclass(cls, clazz)
    ]
parent_subclasses = find_subclasses(app.models,Parent)
parent_subclass_2_related_name = {}
for c in parent_subclasses:
    try:
        parent_subclass_2_related_name[c.__name__] = c.container.field.rel.related_name
    except (AttributeError):
        pass

# define the query and selectively wrapper it    
qs = Container.objects.all()\
    .prefetch_related(Prefetch('parent_list',Parent.objects.select_subclasses()))

def attach_clone(obj):
    original_clone = obj._clone
    def new_clone(*args,**kwargs):
        result = original_clone(*args,**kwargs)
        attach_clone(result) # re-wrapper _clone
        old_prefetch = result._prefetch_related_objects
        def new_prefetch(*args):
            old_prefetch()
            for obj in result._result_cache:
                for s in obj._prefetched_objects_cache['parent_list']:
                    obj._prefetched_objects_cache.setdefault(parent_subclass_2_related_name[s.__class__.__name__],[]).append(s)
        result._prefetch_related_objects = new_prefetch
        return result
    obj._clone = new_clone
attach_clone(qs)

return qs
```